# i want to subtract 3D array in for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I want to subtract prev value with present value but i am stucking in 3d array?

```
print(rain.shape) #(73,80,97)
for j in range(1,72):
      diffrain=np.array(rain[j+1,:,:]-rain[j,:,:])

print(diffrain.shape) #(80,97) only 2d array what about j, here j.shape=73 after subtrcation the value of j will be 72.
```

i want diffrain.shape in 3d (72,80,97) but it showing 2d array.

Comment: Use `np.diff` with axis param?

Comment: i know np.diff but can we do using for loop

Answer (score 0):

you reassigned  `diffrain` for every `j`. Instead, do

```
diffrain = []
for j in range(1,72):
      diffrain.append(rain[j+1,:,:]-rain[j,:,:])

diffrain = np.stack(diffrain)
print(diffrain.shape) # now (72,80,97)
```

Comment: it showing error:    diffrain = np.stack(diffrain)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stack'

Comment: weird, it's should be [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html). You can also use `diffrain = np.array(diffrain)`.

Comment: @MissPriyaKumari If it works, please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: It is not a good idea to store diffrain in a list, when you can make use of arrays.